# How do I iterate list of dictionary in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

How do I iterate list of dictionary returned from curl response in PHP?

Here is structure of a returned response:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [status]                      => open 
    [serviceSpecification]        => https://testdomain.com 
    [expirationDate]              => 
    [name]                        => abcd.com 
    [service]                     => servicekey 
    [domainName]                  => domainname 
    [productInstanceUrl]          => https://anotherinstanceurl.com 
    [createDate]                  => 2019-04-15 
    [serviceSpecificationTextKey] => test.core.key 
    [billingCycle]                => 1 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [status]                      => open 
    [serviceSpecification]        => https://test.net 
    [expirationDate]              => 
    [name]                        => testname 
    [service]                     => https://service.com 
    [domainName]                  => test 
    [productInstanceUrl]          => https://instanceurl.com 
    [createDate]                  => 2019-04-15 
    [serviceSpecificationTextKey] => core.test.key 
    [billingCycle]                => 1 
  ) 
)
```

I tried doing following but not working:

```
foreach ($aboveVariable as $record) {
   echo $record['domainName']; 
}
```

Note:  I believe its more of a how to iterate through list of list in PHP?

Comment: _How do I iterate list of dictionary returned from curl response in PHP?_ Given the response you do it just like you've shown.  What's the problem?

Comment: I believe its more of a how to iterate through list of list in PHP? maybe while writing the response, I made a mistake but the key is there, thats for sure. :)

Comment: First of all it is an array, so you need to get the first value. `foreach($aboveVariable[0] as $key => $value) echo "$key = $value";` or in short `echo $aboveVariable[0]['domainName'];`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller No, the code they have works with that array to echo all domainName from the array.

Comment: your code works just [fine](https://3v4l.org/TsN8d), like I said, there must be something else that you're not showing us.

Comment: Yes I was doing the same but not formatting the entire thing https://3v4l.org/FIGPl

Answer (score 0):

To just show the `domainName` for each then the code you show works.  But based on this *I believe its more of a how to iterate through list of list in PHP?* I would say you just want to loop the main array and then the sub-arrays:

```
foreach($aboveVariable as $record) {
    foreach($record as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name = $value<br>\n"; 
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```

Will show something like:

```
status = open
serviceSpecification = https://testdomain.com
etc...

status = open
serviceSpecification = https://test.net
etc...
```

Comment: This question is either Cannot Repro or a Mega-Duplicate. Either way, Stack Overflow does not need this page to exist.  Please help to reduce the amount of redundant content here.